# Python overidable functions from HTMLParser

Tags: python, html-parser

I understand how to use handle_starttag from HTMLParser but I am very confused how it works under the hood.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#example-html-parser-application

The doc says one needs to override this handle_starttag method and it indeed works as expected.

However when I check the definition in the parent class (HTMLParser), the definition is nothing but a "pass".

So how does handle_starttag work? How does Python know tag is tag while attrs are attributes if the parent definition is empty? 
Happy to clarify more if my question is not clear.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `handle_starttag` is called during parsing when the parser encounters a start tag. See feed which calls goahead which calls parse_starttag which calls handle_starttag.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel: thanks, all clear now, this explains exactly what is under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `handle_starttag` *doesn't* do anything. It's only there to be overridden. Knowing what's a tag and what's an attribute isn't `handle_starttag`'s job; it's the job of other code. *Nothing* is the default `handle_starttag`'s job.

Calling `handle_starttag` is `HTMLParser`'s way of asking subclasses, "hey, do you want to do anything with this start tag I just parsed"? An overridden `handle_starttag` is a subclass's way of responding "yeah, thanks, I'll do the thing I do with start tags". If it's not overridden, it does nothing. Either way, after it's called, parsing just goes on.

Comment: thanks for the fast response, I guess I did not make myself clear. Why handle_starttag actually handles start tag not end tag or anything else? Just because the name has start in it?

Comment: "it's the job of other code", where is this code? how it interacts with handle_starttag?

Comment: @yondchang: Ctrl-F `handle_starttag` in that file and you'll see it.